# Add ActionItems Separately for Each Fragment in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

In my `MainActivity`, I am implementing `ViewPager` that leads towards 2 Fragment. The problem is that m a bit confused with ActionItems where to put them. What I want is that whenever i Swipe between fragments, the `ActionItems` must be different for each Fragment. Can anyone guide me about this.

Currently , I am not Adding menu items on Activity. But only the `ActionItems` of **2nd Fragment** are only showing on both fragments. 
Here is my code :

**`EDITED`**

For **1stFragment** :

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_one, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchWidgetOne);
        SearchView search = new SearchView(getActivity());
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchItem.setActionView(search);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.action_items_one:
                Intent addCrInent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityA.class);
                startActivity(addCrInent);

                return true;
            case  R.id.action_items_two:
                Intent addStIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(addStIntent);

                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }

    }
```

For **2ndFragment**:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchWidgetTwo);
        SearchView search = new SearchView(getActivity());
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchItem.setActionView(search);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.action_items_one_secondMenu:
                Intent addCrInent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityA.class);
                startActivity(addCrInent);

                return true;
            case  R.id.action_items_two_secondMenu:
                Intent addStIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(addStIntent);

                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }

    }
```

For Both Fragments, in MY onCreate i have written this line :

```
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Here is my `menu_one.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchWidgetOne"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_items_one"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_course"/>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_items_two"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_student"/>
```

And Here is my `menu_second.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/searchWidgetTwo"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_items_one_secondMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_course"/>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_items_two_secondMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_student"/>
```

I have also used **`ivalidateOptionMenu()`** in **`onPageSelected()`** but in vain.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with one of my application.
The trick I found (and I say the trick) is, depending your fragment, hide the unused items and show the needed ones.

In the Activity where you manager your fragment, just manage your items as well :

```
private Menu mMenu;

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.note_menu, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    ...
}

private void displayMenu1(boolean display)
{
    mMenu.findItem(<ID>).setVisible(display);
    mMenu.findItem(<ID2>).setVisible(display);
}

private void displayMenu2(boolean display)
{
    mMenu.findItem(<ID>).setVisible(display);
    mMenu.findItem(<ID2>).setVisible(display);
}
```

I'm sure this is not the best solution, and didn't think of any better solution since that.

Comment: Thnx for Your Answer, let me implement it.

Comment: Where do i need to implement it. Coz if i implement it in my Activity, its giving a NullPointerException for menu items.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing something not right in your project. For example, you are using the same drawable (icon) and string (title) for your menus in both `menu_one.xml` and `menu_second.xml`. Use something unique for icons and titles if the menus are supposed to do different functions.

With following changes, [EffectiveNavigation](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/EffectiveNavigation.zip) sample app provided by Android Developers site is giving expected results.

**MainActivity$LaunchpadSectionFragment**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_launchpad, menu);
}
```

**res/menu/fragment_launchpad.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchWidgetOne"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@android:string/search_go"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_items_one"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_plus"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@android:string/ok"/>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity$DummySectionFragment**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_dummy_section, menu);
}
```

**res/menu/fragment_dummy_section.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchWidgetTwo"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@android:string/search_go"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_items_two"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_minus"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@android:string/ok"/>

</menu>
```

**And the result**:

[image: animated screenshot]

Comment: I have followed exxxaaaccctttt code. But now its showing items of Both Fragments together.

Comment: Even i have run the Navigation example u gave, which is running absolutely ok. but why not mine.

Comment: I have changed the icon's drawables , their strings as u mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I provided a working example and you confirmed that it is even working on your end. Now, why it is not working on your project is something difficult to guess with the information you have given. Either you need to figure out what you are doing different there or give us more information and context of your project.